# How to Implement HttpDelete and HttpPut in Asp.Net MVC Core 3.1 c#. Resolve HTTP ERROR 405?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

*Technology Info:*
Framework = Asp.Net Core 3.1
IDE = VisualStudio 2019

*Problem:*
I have a controller with Update and Delete Action Methods. I have UpdateView and DeleteView from where I need to redirect to the respective controller. I have implemented a button that can submit the form. Still I'm facing **HTTP ERROR 405** Issues with **PUT & DELETE**. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance
**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("ModifyEmployee")]
    public IActionResult ModifyEmployee(int employeeId, Malips.Data.Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Malips.Data.Employee employeeDetail = _hrService.EmployeeSystem.UpdateEmployee(employee);
            return View("GetEmployee", employeeDetail);
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public IActionResult DeleteEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        _hrService.EmployeeSystem.DeleteEmployee(employeeId);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

**UpdateView:**

```
@model Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Modify Employee";
}
<div>
    <form asp-controller="Hr" asp-action="ModifyEmployee" asp-route-employeeId="@Model.EmpId">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.EmpId)
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="col-sm-2">First Name</label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="col-sm-10" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**DeleteView:**

```
<form asp-controller="Hr" asp-action="DeleteEmployee" asp-route-employeeId="@Model.EmpId">
    <div class="row card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <label hidden="hidden">@Model.EmpId</label>
            <h5 class="card-title">@Model.FirstName  @Model.LastName</h5>
            <p class="card-text">@Model.Salary </p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Joseph Nannepaga,any update about this case?

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu, Few are suggesting to use Ajax calls. But, I'm looking for the perfect fix i.e., without Ajax nd only with Razor lib.

Comment: Hi @Joseph Nannepaga,I think use  httppost is better than httpput and httpdelete.

Answer (score 0):

The current HTML5  does not support PUT or DELETE in forms. You can use it with ajax or httpclient only. Or you can try @Html.BeginForm razor page template if it is possible. @Html.BeginForm has post metod choice.

For now remove  [ActionName("ModifyEmployee")], [httpput] and [httpdelete] from your action attributes.
And change

```
public IActionResult ModifyEmployee(int employeeId, Malips.Data.Employee employee)
```

to:

```
public IActionResult ModifyEmployee(Employee employee)
```

since you don't use and don't need emploeeId. And remove asp-route-employeeId="@Model.EmpId" from ModifyEmployee view too.

Comment: 1. If we remove action verbs they would become Post by default., so the actual implementation would be wrong. 
2. There is no problem with parameter binding. It's not necessary to remove  1st parameter in Modify (int employeeId, Malips.Data.Employee employee) as it's the standard  update URL notation for our product.
I just need the Implementation of HttpPut & HttpDelete in my project.

Comment: Only students are using  Post, Put ...etc. It is only good for textbooks with  a classic CRUDE . In a real life profies don't use any of them since the real controller can have hundreds actions.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sergey said,You can use it with ajax.Below is a working demo.

**UpdateView:**

```
    <div>
    <form id="update" asp-controller="Hr" asp-action="ModifyEmployee">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.EmpId)
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="col-sm-2">First Name</label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="col-sm-10" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="col-sm-2">First Name</label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="col-sm-10" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#update').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/hr/Modifyemployee",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
}
```

**ModifyEmployee Action**

```
 [HttpPut]
 [ActionName("ModifyEmployee")]
 //remember add this.
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> ModifyEmployee(Employee employee)
 {
        //....
        return new JsonResult(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Hr") });
 }
```

**DeleteView:**

```
 <div>
    <form id="delete" asp-controller="Hr" asp-action="DeleteEmployee" asp-route-employeeId="@Model.EmpId">
        <div class="row card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <label hidden="hidden">@Model.EmpId</label>
                <h5 class="card-title">@Model.FirstName  @Model.LastName</h5>
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@section scripts
{
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            type: "delete",
            url: "/hr/DeleteEmployee?id=" + @Model.EmpId,
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
}
```

**DeleteEmployee Action**

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEmployee(int id)
{
   //......
   return new JsonResult(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index", "hr") });
}
```

**Test Result:**
[image]